# Instantiating Java objects from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

I can easily instantiate a `java.lang.String` object with a blank constructor like:

```
var classString = obj.getClass().forName ('java.lang.String');
var objectString = classString.newInstance();
```

but when I want to obtain a reference to another constructor, my code:

```
var array = [classString];
var constr = classString.getConstructor (array);

objectString = ">>>>>>>>";
var objectString2 = constr.newInstance ([objectString]);
```

produces empty string as if the zero-arguments constructor had been called.

The `constr` variable always points to `String()` rather than `String(String toCopy)`

How can I get and call constructors with arguments?

Comment: "Instantiate" is the word you're looking for (not "initiate", which means "begin"). Or "create". (I've edited for you.)

Comment: How are you running the JavaScript within a Java environment? Rhino?

Comment: From inside the browser.

Comment: @ OGP: What browser? What bridging technology? What is `obj` in your code above?

Comment: Android Browser. 'obj' - apparently the view of browser.

Comment: @ OGP: I'd put that information right up front in the question. What do you mean by *"apparently"* the view of the browser? It's your code, you should know what `obj` is, specifically and certainly.

Comment: I'm nothing like a J/S developer, so have to say 'apparently'. I cannot find information about how it all works. I was made busy with a very trivial code where Java object successfully created within J/S code and the constructor used without parameters. I have some Java experience and know how reflection works. I used to implement code with reflections when creating objects with parametrized constructors. The question is if I can do it from J/S?

Comment: 'obj' is an object of 'android.webkit.SearchBoxImpl' class.